# A problem regarding image handling on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing

```
from skimage import io
photo=io.imread('myimage.jpg')
print(type(photo)) 

photo.shape
print(photo.shape)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(photo)
```

This is my code on my editor. I don't use anacona distribution or jupyter notebook. print(type(photo)) and print(photo.shape) lines works but plt.imshow(photo) doesn't.How to fix it? Though ,I have installed those necessary modules and packeges. 
My second question , is there another python distribution which is so efficient like anaconda.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn’t work"?

Comment: May be `plt.show()` at the end will help.

Comment: @mkrieger1 that line plt.imshow(photo) supposed to show that image which i have have accessed .But this line does not show any output.